# events.js:288. :Cannot read property 'items' of null

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I have tried restarting the server multiple times. I also removed the node modules and installed it again. I also cleared the cache and also restarted VS code many time. Nothing seems to be working. Now after writing `foundList.items.push(item);` i cannot add items to my route directory as well. Before this i was able to add or delete items from the route directory. Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is my code for Express:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;
  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName,
  });

  //Check id the user tried to add the list is default list or the custom list. Then find the custom list and add the new item and redirect to the custom list i.e ///listName
  if (listName === "Today") {
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    List.findOne({ name: listName }, function (err, foundList) {
      foundList.items.push(item);
      foundList.save();
      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    });
  }
});
```

Here is my EJS code as well.

```
    <div class="box heading">
  <h1><%= listTitle %></h1>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <% newListItems.forEach(function(item) { %>
  <form action="/delete" method="POST">
    <div class="item">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="checkbox"
        value="<%= item._id %>"
        onChange="this.form.submit()"
      />
      <p><%=item.name%></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <%});%>

  <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="newItem"
      name="newItem"
      autocomplete="off"
    />
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If `foundList` is null, `err` is probably set. Try checking and throwing `err` if it's set before trying to use `foundList`.

Comment: foundList is not null. It says cannot read property 'items' of null.

Comment: The only line in your program that has a `.items` property read is this: `foundList.items`. So if that's not the crashing line, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, that is the crashing line. I have tried all the options i could find. It still cannot be solved. I still get an error that says "cannot read property 'items' of null"

Comment: I don't know what else to say--if `foundList` is null, trying to do `null.items` is going to throw an error. When `err` is set, it means that the query you're trying to run failed and you should throw it or _not_ access `foundList.items`. Instead, the code happily ignores `err` and indexes right into `.items` regardless of whether `err` was set. `if (err) throw err;` should be before `foundList.items`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my Udemy training course I am doing. I am pretty new to coding and have spent couple of hours trying to fix the same code. Anyways:

try to change the line:  foundList.items.push(item); to singular: foundList.item.push(item); I can't see your listSchema in the code. Check it and see if you have "item" or "items".
const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  item: [itemsSchema]
};
I had item declared in the schema but was calling items in  "foundList.items.push(item), and the server was crushing all the times.

Answer (score 0):

It is landing into error as `listName` case is not matching with the list items available. require and install `lodash` and try using:

`const listName= _.lowerCase(req.body.list);`